# Is there a way to search a text the user has loaded from a file for a specific word and color it?

Tags: c#, console-application

The user specifies a file path which then inserts all the readable content into a string, but I now have problems searching this string for a word entered by the user and coloring it differently if hits are present.

```
 Console.WriteLine("Please enter the path of the document to be searched");

        do
        {

            text = Helper.TryToReadFile();
        } while (text == null);

        Console.WriteLine("Choosen Text:\n---------------------------------------\n");
        Console.WriteLine(text);
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------\n");
        //
        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to search for whole words ?");
        bool decisionForWholeWords = Helper.ConvertToBool(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Should the spelling be observed ?");
        bool decisionForSpelling = Helper.ConvertToBool(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: few questions: 1. do you have problems with the word inside a string? 2.where do you want to color the hits? 3.what is the original file format?

Comment: So I want the user to enter a word like apple for example.  Before that a text file is opened and the whole readable content is inserted into a string. Now it should be checked if apple is present in the string with the data of the text file (can also be present several times). If there are 1 or more hits the text is displayed in the console and only the word apple has the color red and the rest of the text is black.

Comment: Actually, the format doesn't matter, because I search the contents of the file for readable characters and these are all inserted into the string, so I have to search the string somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple and basic logic

```
  public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string txt = "this is a an example string";
            string wordToFind = "example string";
            bool phraseFound = false;
            var splittedTxt = txt.Split(' ');
            var wordToFindList = wordToFind.Split(' ');
            foreach (var item in splittedTxt)
            {
                if (wordToFindList.Any(item.Contains))
                {
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    phraseFound = true;
                }
                Console.Write(item);
                if (phraseFound) // reset color
                {
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                    phraseFound = false;
                }
                Console.Write(" ");
            }


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

example output [image]

Comment: In itself, it works for single words. Can I realize that it is also recognized when I search for the term apple and in the text is apple tree that he then marks apple? Because currently he does not recognize the word because it must be written completely the same. But I am really grateful for the current solution.

Comment: if you are worried about casing, you set both strings to lower

Comment: @eXoDuS fixed my answer to work with any number or word(s)